# How to use wildcard for matching two column vales being same

Tags: sql, wildcard

How to use wildcard for matching two column vales being same, for instance, city name is delhi and capital is delhi ct. To retrieve all those records what would be the query? suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: And add the sql db as well

Comment: Table columns are like below. The condition is to match the similar word in two columns name and capital and print those.                                                                       name         capital         population continent gdp
Luxemberg Luxemberg 100m         Europe 10m
Vetican City Vetican City 200m         SA         1M

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, I think you are just looking to compare two columns here. You can do this by looking for one string column in another string column. In SQL server, you could use:

```
;with cte as
(select 'Delhi' as City,'Delhi ct' as Capital 
 UNION
 select 'A' as City,'B' as Capital)

select *,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(City,Capital,1)>0 then 'Match'
             WHEN CHARINDEX(Capital,City,1)>0 then 'Match'
             ELSE 'No Match'
             END as Match_Check
from cte
```

Hope this helps.